# Pandas: Querying column value based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Python list of strings and a Pandas DataFrame having columns X, Y, Z for example. I need to sequentially query the value of column X in the dataframe where the column `Y == mylist[index]`. I have tried the following to no avail:

```
filelist = glob.glob('/somedir/*.txt')

for f in filelist:
    f = os.path.basename(f)
    df.loc[df['Y'] == f, 'X'].item()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `df.X` where the value of `df.Y` is in some list you can use [`pandas.Series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df[df['Y'].isin([os.path.basename(f) for f in filelist])]['X']
```

To iterate through the results you can use [`pandas.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
for x in df[df['Y'].isin([os.path.basename(f) for f in filelist])]['X'].values:
    print x
```

Or, depending on what you want to do to the results, you can use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df[df['Y'].isin([os.path.basename(f) for f in filelist])]['X'].apply(some_function)
```